State the 3rd and 4th levels of the von Neumann hierarchy explicitly (as strings of curly brackets)
I'm somewhat new to this site, and I tried to do my due diligence in searching for a previous answer to this question, but I worry that I may have missed it. This question seems so elementary that it's hard to believe that it's not answered on here in some form or another. If anyone knows about a previous answer to this, I would appreciate a link to that page, and also any tips on how to search efficiently for previous answers. Thank you.
The problem:
Define $V_{\alpha +1} := V_\alpha \cup \mathcal{P}V_\alpha, V_0 = \varnothing$. ($\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set operation)
(1) List all the members of $V_3$. (2) List all the members of $V_4$. (That is, write each as a string of curly brackets and "$\varnothing$" symbols.)
I'm self-studying Enderton's Elements of Set Theory (this corresponds to Chapter 1, Problem 7). Skipping around the book, I'm absolutely fascinated by it, but I'm only in the preliminary section on "Naive Set Theory," and I'm already stumbling haha. I can't for the life of me keep this mess of brackets straight, nor can I even confidently form power sets (facepalm). I would especially appreciate a precise description of an algorithm for moving from $V_k$ to $V_{k + 1}$. I tend to be good at such things- like listing permutations in an organized way in combinatorics, etc.- but this one is making me scratch my head. Thanks :)

These are not the Von-Neumann ordinals, they are the levels of the Von-Neumann hierarchy.

@spaceisdarkgreen Thanks— will edit the title. I suspect that the distinction is over my head, as I’m still in the section on “naive” set theory, but if there’s an easy way to explain it would be appreciated :)

The Von-Neumann ordinals are a simpler hierarchy, where we iterate the function $S(x) = x\cup{x}$ rather than the power set. So the 0-th ordinal (typically just called 0) is the emptyset, the first ordinal (called 1) is ${\emptyset}$ and has one element, $2={\emptyset, {\emptyset}}$ has two elements, 3 has 3, etc.

To get from $V_k$ to $V_{k+1}$, you take the set consisting of

Every element of $V_k$ AND
Every subset of $V_k$ (this is the powerset part)

So
$$V_0 = \{\}$$
$$V_1 = \{\{\}\}$$
$$V_2 = \{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}$$
Now to get $V_3$ we consider every subset of $V_2$. Since $|V_2| = 2$ there are four subsets: the empty set, two singletons, and all of $V_2$. Note that the elements of $V_2$ are also subsets of $V_2$, so we don't need to worry about those.
$$V_3 = \{\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\{\}\}\},\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}\}$$
For $V_4$ we'll have eight elements, and the result probably won't fit on a single line.

$V_4$ has 16 elements.

Also, funny story, I’ve definitely seen a textbook exercise to do $V_5$ before , which I don’t think was very well thought out, assuming it wasn’t a joke.

@spaceisdarkgreen It was actually exactly when I realized that $V_4$ has $16$ elements and not $8$ that I threw up my hands and made this post haha

@trim I feel like knowing how many elements there are in $V_n$ is half the battle. Hopefully you can see that writing out $V_5$ would be an extremely time-consuming task by hand and it would be better to write a computer program, and writing out $V_6$ would be impossible with any physically feasible amount of computing resources.

@spaceisdarkgreen Sorry for another question-- you've been very helpful so far-- but is the answer above trustworthy? You pointed out that $V_4$ will have $16$ elements and not $8$, but is the analysis above otherwise correct?

@trim yes, don’t see any other issues with this or the other answer.

@spaceisdarkgreen Speaking of the computer program-- I may just write one to solve this problem. I think if I can do that then I've understood the important parts of this problem, and any remaining difficulties are unimportant ones.

This problem is simplified if we introduce some notation.
I understand that you are asked to describe the sets explicitly, but it makes sense to describe it first using an abbreviation, and then unravel each part of the abbreviation.
Let
∅ = 0
{∅} = {0} = 1
{{∅},∅} = {0,1} = 2
.
.
.
{0,...,n-1} = n
Note: Given a natural number n, we construct n+1 by taking the Successor of n, S(n) where
S(n) = n ∪ {n}
We have that:
$V_0$ =  0
$V_1$ = {0} = 1
$V_2$ = {1,0} = 2
$V_3$ = {0,1,2,{1}}
$V_4$ = {0,1,2,{1},$V_3$,{2},{{1}},{0,1},{0,2},{0,{1}},{1,2},{1,{1}},{2,{1}},{1,2,{1}},{0,2,{1}},3}
Now it is just an exercise unraveling each defined term.
To understand an algorithm to finding subsets, I reccomend you study the the proof of the cardinality of P(x).
If |X| = n
|P(x)| = $2^n$
Key Idea: Given any Subset of X, an element x of X is either in the subset, or is Not.

Thanks. I actually already had an intimate understanding of why $|\mathcal{P}A| = 2^{|A|}$, but I hadn't thought to leverage that in order to answer this question XD.

That's great! It's nice to see your efforts in the subject. As a very broad piece of advice, whenever you are working on a problem, one strategy is to lay out all potentially relevent tools! So, if you have a HW related to the powerset, try and remember that you have the big theorems in the background to rely on! And you should be thinking, how can I bring in this result etc...

I give the same advice to my students regularly, using it myself is another thing haha

Edit:
As I said in the original post, I’m somewhat new to this site. This post has been downvoted, which I view as an opportunity to improve; however, there is no comment or explanation. Leave a message?
$V_4 = 
\big\{ 
    \varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}, 
    \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{\{\varnothing\}\}\}, \{\{\varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}\}, \\
    \{\{\varnothing\}, \varnothing, \{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}\}, \{\{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\}, 
    \{\{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\{\varnothing\}, \varnothing\}\}, \{\{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\}, \\
    \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\}, 
    \{\varnothing, \{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\}, \{\{\varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\}, \\
    \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\}
\big\}$
Thanks to all for the help. Hints for any possible future students:
I found it helpful to (1) Convince myself of the number of elements in $V_4$, (2) Work "top-down" by first opening brackets for the entirety of $V_4$, then counting how many subsets there would be of size 1, 2, 3, ... , and opening brackets and adding commas accordingly (Sub-Hint: There will be 1 subset of size 0, 4 subsets of size 1, 6 subsets of size 2, 4 subsets of size 3, 1 subset of size 4; totaling 16 and corresponding to the 4th row of Pascal's Triangle), and (3) Make principled use of my computer's copy-paste function :).
Other Reflections: There's a part of me that feels that the author asking for $V_4$ was gratuitous. There's another part of me that feels that if I had stopped at $V_3$, I would have missed out on some understanding of the combinatorial structure of each $V_\alpha$. In any case, I'm happy to be moving on to the next problem :)
